# Define a protocol that returns itself with a different associated value

Tags: swift

I want to implement something like the following:

```
struct Implementation1<Value>: Protocol1 {

    let v: Value

    func test<Next : Protocol1>(next: Next) -> Implementation1<Next.Value> {
    }
}
```

How can I define `Protocol` such that in test function I can tell it to return `Self` specialized to `Next.Value`

My attempt was

```
protocol Protocol1 {
    associatedtype Value

    var v: Value { get }

    func test<Next: Protocol1>(next: Next) -> Self<Value>
}
```

but of course this doesn't work since we cannot specialize Self.